# How to create a function that calculates maximum average grade?

Tags: c

Function **int getMax(student *students, int entry_size)** should calculate max grade among all students. **student** here is structure, and ***students** is array, entry_size already can found using function that is indicated below. Trick with **getMax** function is that it should use recursion;
File format that contains data is as follows:

```
Name Surname ID Grade
Name Surname ID Grade
...
```

I have done part of code where it scans and returns an array of students:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   char firstName[30], secondName[30];
   int ID;
   int grade;
} student;

typedef struct {
   int ID;
   int avgGrade;
} topThreeAvg;

student *readStudents(char *fileName, int* entry_size, int *all_ids, int* studentSize){
/*
all_ids is an array for counting the amount of grades per student. studentSize is the actual number of students (for example, in students1.txt it is 2)
*/
   FILE *openedFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

   if(openedFile == NULL){
      printf("Cannot open a file");
      exit (0);
   }

   char entrySize[10];
   fscanf(openedFile, "%[^\n]", entrySize);

   int numberOfEntries = atoi(entrySize);
   *entry_size = numberOfEntries;

   student *students;
   if ( NULL == ( students = malloc(numberOfEntries * sizeof *students))) {
      printf ("Error with memory allocation");
      exit (0);
   }

   int i;
    for(i=0; i < numberOfEntries; i++){
        if (4 != fscanf(openedFile, "%s %s %d %d"
        , students[i].firstName
        , students[i].secondName
        , &students[i].ID
        , &students[i].grade)) {
            exit (0);
        }
    }

    return students;
  }
```

I tried to implement the function, but it gives very huge number:

```
int max_in(student *students, int entry_size){
     int curr_val = students->grade;
     if (entry_size == 1) {
        return curr_val;
     }

     int max_in_rest = max_in(&students->ID+1, entry_size-1);

     return curr_val > max_in_rest ? curr_val : max_in_rest;
}
```

How to make a function recursive and find that maximum grade among all students?

Comment: @kiranBiradar edited with own attempt

Comment: Why do you want to make it recursive?

Comment: @klutt I would love to do that w/o recursion =) Problem is that it was asked to do so

Comment: Post sample data, AFAIK, the names are too big.  `"%s %s %d %d"` --> `"%29s %29s %d %d"`

Comment: OT:  regarding struct definitions like:  `typedef struct {
   int ID;
   int avgGrade;
} topThreeAvg;`  do not create anonymous structs, they are very difficult to debug.  Rather give each struct a 'tag' name so the debugger can display each field within the struct.

Comment: recursion 'eats up' the stack.  Windows OS allocates a 'relatively' small stack for a program.  So if there are a lot of students, the program can crash from a stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Try as below.

```
   int max(int x, int y){
       return x > y ? x : y;
   }

  int max_in(student *students, int entry_size){

     if (entry_size <= 0){
        return -1;
     }
     else {
        return max(students[entry_size-1].grade, max_in(students, entry_size-1))
     }
  }
```